# wsgi.py is missing and manage.py is there instead

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, uwsgi, wsgi

so I'm trying to follow this: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html

and it says "If the file /home/foobar/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py (or whatever you have called your project) does not exist, you are very probably using an old (< 1.4) version of Django. In such a case you need a little bit more configuration:"

but I'm using 1.10.5 version of Django and instead of wsgi.py it has manage.py ...... what should I do to complete that step in the tutorial? should i just use manage.py?

Comment: The `wsgi.py` lies in the directory where `settings.py` in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the uwsgi docs that you quote have `.../myproject/myproject/...` in the path, that is, they have `myproject` twice. Indeed, in recent Django versions when you start a project `manage.py` is placed in the top-level directory (usually something like `/home/foobar/myproject`), whereas `wsgi.py` in the `myproject` subdirectory of that. So `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` are in locations similar to the following:

```
/home/foobar/myproject/manage.py
/home/foobar/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```